# How to get File size through storage reference in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am getting 0 while doing this:

```
uploadRef.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                    size=storageMetadata.getSizeBytes();
                }
            });
```

Also 0 in this,

```
 UploadTask uploadTask = uploadRef.putFile(returnUri);           
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    size[0] = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getSizeBytes();
```

And this is giving error: Task is not yet complete

```
float test =uploadRef.getMetadata().getResult().getSizeBytes();
```

Comment: This is a bit silly but have you checked to make sure the item has been uploaded to Storage?

Comment: Its uploaded to Storage. I can save Filename to Database but apparently size is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake related to scope of variable "size". While storing in database it was not getting the updated value of variable "size".

Method 2 works great.